# magento view mode as grid with multiple grid options

Tags: magento, grid

Hoping you can help as im not sure how to approach this. Cant seem to find any good resources on it.

Trying to create a grid view on the list.phtml. However I want to let the user decide on if they want 2, 3 or 4 items per row.

Like on this website:
http://www.missguided.co.uk/clothing/category/tops

Also what template file are those grid options/ icons html defined in as I cant seem to find it.

Any help and examples would be appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a script which used the magento grid param to determine what the user had selected. From there I just resized my images accordingly.

Hope this helps anyone else wanting to create this effect.